# Robot Framework uac windows 10

Tags: python, windows-10, robotframework, uac

While using robot framework in windows 10 the python -m robot is launched with admin privileges. Does this mean admin privileges will be passed down to all sub processes that are started?

Comment: By default, yes. If an elevated process starts other processes, the other processes it starts will also be elevated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, admin privileges will be passed into sub-processed. I would not recommend to run test with admin privileges, the safest and recommended way is to use virtualenv without admin privileges.